# Does c# offer a direct way to alias a property name?

Tags: c#, properties, alias

Does c# (any version) offer an improved way to alias a property name? In AccountBase, I use the string Username to identify the account, but in NonstandardAccount I want the client (consumer of the API) to use CustomerNumber to prevent confusion.

Here is my code:

```
public abstract class AccountBase
{
    public string Username { get => Username; set => Username = value; }
}

public class StandardAccount
{
    // The username is the ID
}


public class NonstandardAccount : AccountBase
{
    // The Username or CustomerNumber is the ID
    public string CustomerNumber { get => Username; set => Username = value; }

    // OR ideally, but I don't think this works
    public string CustomerNumber => Username; 
}
```

I could forgo adding a CustomerNumber property and just document that it is the same as the Username, but it isn't clear. I could just leave my implementation as is, but extra storage for the sake of clarity may not be a good tradeoff.

Comment: For your  `AccountBase` just use `{get;set;}` if you do not provide any private backerfield. `StandardAccount` probably needs to inherit `AccountBase` according to your description. If your `NonstandardAccount` is a model you could get away with `{get => Username; set => Username = value;}` but having sideeffects in setters is frowned upon I think. For MVC and WPF you can work with Attributes to "rename" the viewmodel-fields for the display (DisplayNameAttribute) afaik.

Comment: The current implementation still exposes the `UserName` property of `AccountBase` in `NonstandardAccount`.

Comment: @Odrai hiding them by new would violate Liskov - so I wouldnt do that...

Comment: Your 2nd version ov CustomerNumber in Nonstandard is fine -- if you remove the 1st one.

Comment: @PatrickArtner 2nd version works, but the `Username` property of AccountBase is still exposed to the end customer of the API.

Comment: @Odrai  That's fine and deliberate.  Internally, I want to use the username since all the objects are faceless, but the caller can use either one.

Comment: If you're making a web API and you're serializing to JSON using JSON.Net, you could write a custom contract resolver to rename the property when serializing/deserializing.

Comment: @PatrickArtner  What?!  You mean the CustomerNumber  => Username works?  I just jived it and expected it not to work at all.  I thought it requires a signature like (value) => {}. Man c# is the wholly and holy grail of all languages!

Comment: Not a holy grail , C#7 syntactic sugar. ... still @john s points are valid - if you expose your api via web you might want to simply change the name by contract and in the Serialization/Deserialization process.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yeah, but that syntactic sugar packs a lot of sweetness in the punch without it turning into Jonestown koolaid like JavaScript or Lisp.    Bjarne said inside c++, there's a simpler language dying to come out.  I say, it's been out for a while now, it C#!  Add you comment as an answer so I can pick it as an answer.

Comment: @PatrickArtner  I'll answer my own question, but if you later add your answer I will retract my own answer. I think other people should benefit from it too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Patrick Artner, I found not only an answer, but the ideal answer. It was right in my source code all along, but I didn't trust my intuition.

```
public class NonstandardAccount : AccountBase
{
    // Does work and works perfectly! Username is still accessible
    public string CustomerNumber => Username; 
}
```

A new hard learnt lesson: Just because your intuition was wrong on many occasions, doesn't mean you should discredit it as a pathological liar.

Comment: There is one limitation though: it only offers a getter. This does not offer a setter, and if you are working with MVVM, then INotifyPropertyChanged will not fire for your alias.

Comment: True. In this particular case, however, you might want it only on the base class' property only so it can work across all subclasses. In other cases it may be computed from other properties.  It would be interesting to know if the compiler optimizes away the alias or leaves it in for the sake of reflection.